# Why can't I push into a Vec of dyn Trait unless I use a temporary variable?

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism, trait-objects

This is my code:

```rust
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;

trait Trait {}

fn push<E: Trait>(e: E) {
    let mut v: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>> = Vec::new();
    
    // let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(e)));
    // v.push(x); // error

    v.push(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(e)))); // works fine
}
```

The `v.push(x)` raises this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:12
   |
7  | fn push<E: Trait>(e: E) {
   |         - this type parameter
...
12 |     v.push(x);
   |            ^ expected trait object `dyn Trait`, found type parameter `E`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<std::boxed::Box<dyn Trait>>>`
              found struct `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<std::boxed::Box<E>>>`
```

But if I push the value (constructed with the exact same value and types) directly into the vector it compiles without error.

So why doesn't the first version compile? And what should I change to make it so that I can use `x` before pushing it into the vector?

Comment: `Rc<RefCell<Box<_>>>` is probably unnecessary; you can usually get away with `Rc<RefCell<_>>`. If you remove the `Box` layer, [both work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74a45b83650bfa8545979b3edcae3ae9) because `Rc<RefCell<T>>` will coerce to `Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>` the same way `Box<T>` does.

Comment: Commenting to link to [how unsized coercions work](/q/52288980/3650362) and [another recent question whose answers you may find enlightening](/q/61799081/3650362).

Comment: Also [How do I pass Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>> to a function accepting Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>?](/q/30861295/3650362) which elaborates a little on my first comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all in the type inference. When you write:

```rust
v.push(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(e))));
```

Rust can tell from that context that the argument to `RefCell::new()` must be a `Box<dyn Trait>`, so despite supplying a `Box<E>`, it coerces it to the former type. When you write this on the other hand:

```rust
let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(e)));
v.push(x); // compile error
```

Rust first infers that `x` of type `Rc<RefCell<Box<E>>>` and you can no longer `push` it into a `vec` of `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>`. You can change this by putting an explicit type annotation in your `let` binding to tell Rust upfront that you really do want a `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>`:

```rust
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;

trait Trait {}

fn push<E: Trait>(e: E) {
    let mut v: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>> = Vec::new();

    let x: Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(e)));
    v.push(x); // compiles
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6561e7f2bf399f34afc52ba093c0705)

The important thing to understand here is that `E` *is not the same* as `dyn Trait`. `E` is some known concrete implementation of `Trait` while `dyn Trait` is a trait object with its underlying concrete implementation erased.