# How to move a Vec<Box<dyn Trait>> Into Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>>

Tags: casting, rust, traits

I have a `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>` as input, and I want to store its elements in a `Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>>`. What is the best way to do it?

I tried with:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Trait {}

fn main() {
    let mut source: Vec<Box<dyn Trait>> = Vec::new();
    let mut dest: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>> = Vec::new();

    for s in source {
        let d = Rc::new(RefCell::new(s.as_ref()));
        dest.push(d);
    }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&dyn Trait: Trait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:19
   |
12 |         dest.push(d);
   |                   ^ the trait `Trait` is not implemented for `&dyn Trait`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Trait`
```

Is it actually possible or am I required to change the input type?

Comment: The problem isn't the casting, it's that a `RefCell` needs to own its data, so you can't construct a `RefCell<dyn Trait>` at all.

You will need to change the type to something like `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>>`

Comment: Or even `Vec<Box<RefCell<dyn Trait>>>`, I saw there is a conversion `Rc::from<T>(Box<T>)`.

Answer (score 1):

Although `RefCell<dyn Trait>` is a valid type, since the declaration of [`RefCell<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) allows `T: ?Sized`, there does not currently appear to be a way to create one from outside the module, other than [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CRefCell%3CU%3E%3E), which requires starting with a sized value.

However, you should be able to use `unsafe` code to convert to a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html), since both have `#[repr(transparent)]`.

Comment: Well, you can create one with an unsized coercion, but that won't help the OP, as they start with an unsized value.

Answer (score 1):

If you control `Trait`, one option is to simply implement it for `Box<dyn Trait>` by deferring to the inner implementation:

```
// We could implement Trait only for Box<dyn Trait>, but usually what you want
// is to implement it for all Boxes of things that are Trait instead
impl<T: ?Sized + Trait> Trait for Box<T> {}

fn pushes(dest: &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>>, source: Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>) {
    for s in source {
        dest.push(Rc::new(RefCell::new(s)));
    }
}
```

Be aware this wraps the already-`Box`ed object behind a second pointer (`Rc`) so if you are using `dest` in a performance-sensitive algorithm it will have to dereference it twice rather than once. If you are able to restructure the code so you can accept `Box<T: Trait>`, you could eliminate the double indirection by moving the `T` out of the `Box` and into a `RefCell`.

## Related questions

- [Why can't I push into a Vec of dyn Trait unless I use a temporary variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61972343/3650362)
- [How do I pass Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>> to a function accepting Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30861295/3650362) (a similar case where the double indirection could be eliminated)
- [What does "Sized is not implemented" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/3650362) (explains why `?Sized` is needed in the above example)