# How to create a Rc<RefCell<>> of a self mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a trait for `VirtualTapInterface`. The `receive` function of this trait should create a `TxToken` struct, where the `lower` property must be an `Rc<RefCell<VirtualTapInterface>>` containing the current `VirtualTapInterface`, that is `self`

```
impl<'a> Device<'a> for VirtualTapInterface {
    type TxToken = TxToken;

    fn receive(&'a mut self) -> Option<(Self::RxToken, Self::TxToken)> {
                let tx = TxToken { lower: Rc::new(RefCell::new(*self))};
```

I tried this but I get that

> cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a mutable reference
>
> move occurs because `*self` has type
>   `phy::virtual_tun::VirtualTapInterface`, which does not implement the
>   `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)

How is it possible to create a `Rc<RefCell<>>` of a self mutable reference?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976226/how-to-move-a-vecboxdyn-trait-into-vecrcrefcelldyn-trait

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the signature to `fn receive(self) -> ...` to take ownership. Cloning or taking a box could also work.

Another option is to use [`mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), [`mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html), or [`mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

Comment: I cannot change the signatures, they're from a Trait. What you mean cloning? From what?

Comment: Using `self.clone()` instead of `*self` (if possible).

Comment: cloning will create a copy, right? I need to have a reference to the same object, so cloning is not an option.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yeah. Would one of the `mem::*` functions work? It's not possible to have an `Rc<RefCell<_>>` to an unowned object.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs To be able to use `Rc<RefCell<_>>` you need to ownership, which means you need to either take ownership by using one of the `mem::*` functions or  cloning the object, or you need to already have ownership, by taking `self` or `self: Box<Self>` instead of `&mut self`.