# Using Trait Object for Struct - ERROR: wrong number of type arguments

Tags: rust, traits

I'm a total newbie to Rust, and I am facing with a problem using "Trait Object"...

For now, I have `App` struct with `panels` field which is a Vec of `WavePanel` struct which implements `Panel` trait.
Since I have more that implement `Panel`, I wanted `panels` to become more generic.
So, I tried specifying `Panel` as a Trait Object for the field, but it does not work....

This is how it currently looks (BEFORE the change):

https://github.com/minagawah/perlin-experiment/blob/6e8064140daedc0767733898621c951619ff4467/src_for_wasm/perlin-wave/src/app.rs#L14

```rust
use crate::panels::wave::WavePanel;
use crate::panels::Panel;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct App {
    points: Vec<Point>,
    points_prev: Vec<Point>,
    panels: Vec<WavePanel>, // <-- `WavePanel` struct works just fine.
}

impl App {
    pub fn new(config: &Config) -> Result<Self, String> {
        let color: String = config.color.clone();
        let color2: String = config.color2.clone();

        let mut panels = vec![];
        for panel in &config.panels {
            let id = panel.id.clone();
            match id.as_str() {
                "wave" => {
                    panels.push(WavePanel::new(
                        id.as_str(),
                        color.as_str(),
                        color2.as_str(),
                    )?);
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        Ok(App {
            points: vec![],
            points_prev: vec![],
            panels: panels,
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the `Panel` trait:

```rust
pub trait Panel<G: Graphics> {
    fn g(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<G>>;

    fn reset(&mut self) {
        if let Ok(mut g) = self.g().try_borrow_mut() {
            let (width, height) = g.size();
            g.reset(width, height);
        };
    }
}
```

This is how `WavePanel` implements `Panel` trait:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct WavePanel {
    id: String,
    g: Rc<RefCell<WaveGraphics>>,
    graph_type: Rc<Cell<GraphType>>,
}

impl Panel<WaveGraphics> for WavePanel {
    fn g(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<WaveGraphics>> {
        self.g.clone()
    }
}
```

And, here is what I tried (AFTER):

```rust
use crate::panels::wave::WavePanel;
use crate::panels::Panel;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct App {
    points: Vec<Point>,
    points_prev: Vec<Point>,
    panels: Vec<Box<dyn Panel>>, // <-- This does not work...
}

impl App {
    pub fn new(config: &Config) -> Result<Self, String> {
        let color: String = config.color.clone();
        let color2: String = config.color2.clone();

        let mut panels = vec![];
        for panel in &config.panels {
            let id = panel.id.clone();
            match id.as_str() {
                "wave" => {
                    // Pushing it into Box this time.
                    panels.push(Box::new(
                        WavePanel::new(
                            id.as_str(),
                            color.as_str(),
                            color2.as_str(),
                        )?
                    ));
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        Ok(App {
            points: vec![],
            points_prev: vec![],
            panels: panels,
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/app.rs:15:25
   |
15 |     panels: Vec<Box<dyn Panel>>,
   |                         ^^^^^ expected 1 type argument

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: could not compile `perlin-wave`
```

Shouldn't `Box<dyn Panel>` be explicit enough?
Tried so many things, and still no luck...
Please, I desperately need your help....

#### Edit: SOLVED (2021.3.4)

For the incorrect usage of the trait object, kmdreko was right. What I had for the trait was not `Panel` but `Panel<G: Graphics>`, and they are totally different.
As kmdreko mentioned, I stopped feeding `G` to `Panel` trait, and I replaced `G` with `dyn Graphics` (for the field `g`), and that nailed it!
It resolved the initial error.

However, there arose another problem...
When I actually push the struct `WavePanel` which derives `Panel` trait to `panels: Vec<Box<dyn Panel>>`, I got the error saying: `expected trait object "dyn Panel", found struct "WavePanel"`. This is a problem about implementing a heterogeneous vec, and it is not kmdreko's fault. As far as the original question in concern, kmdreko's answer should be the correct answer.
For this, I found an explanation in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972343/why-cant-i-push-into-a-vec-of-dyn-trait-unless-i-use-a-temporary-variable#61972461).
So, it was about Rust inferring `WavePanel` struct locally instead of `dyn Panel` trailt object. Right when I create `Box::new(WavePanel::new(..))`, now I explicitly tell that I want the trait object `Vec<Box<dyn Panel>>`, and it fixed it.

There was another problem....
Since it relates to the topic, I thought it is worth it to leave a note as well...
So, I have the field `g` in `Panel` now having `dyn Graphics` instead of `G` in `Panel`. A similar situation happened now to `Graphics` trait. Just like I had `WavePanel` struct for `Panel` trait, I have `WaveGraphics` struct for `Graphics` trait. In a way, Rust is now confused with the type for `g` field defined in `Panel`... For this issue, I decided to derive `Any` trait for `Graphics` trait. As long as I define `as_any_mut()` to always return `Any` struct in `Graphics` trait, when I actually want to use it, for instance, `g.draw()`, I can always convert the trait object into `Any`, and do this: `g.as_any_mut().downcast_mut::<WaveGraphics>()` .

For the final diff (for the all fix) is found [here](https://github.com/minagawah/perlin-experiment/commit/530a82dc2abcb0399603a3460907c317623e2b03).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't `Box<dyn Panel>` be explicit enough?

No, you've defined `Panel` to be generic; `Panel<A>` and `Panel<B>` are different traits. If you want `Panel` to be used regardless of the graphics type, it can't be generic.

If `g()` is only there to support `reset()` you can remove it:

```
pub trait Panel {
    fn reset(&mut self);
}

impl Panel for WavePanel {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        if let Ok(mut g) = self.g.try_borrow_mut() {
            let (width, height) = g.size();
            g.reset(width, height);
        };
    }
}
```

Or if `g()` is still necessary to get the graphics object generically, make it dynamic as well:

```
pub trait Panel {
    fn g(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn Graphics>>;
                           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    fn reset(&mut self) {
        if let Ok(mut g) = self.g().try_borrow_mut() {
            let (width, height) = g.size();
            g.reset(width, height);
        };
    }
}

impl Panel for WavePanel {
    fn g(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn Graphics>> {
        self.g.clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will leave `g()` as is since `Panel` trait does not know `g` field which belongs to `WavePanel` struct.
But, for `dyn Graphics`, yay! That is a significant breakthrough! Thanks!
Though, now I get: `expected trait object "dyn Panel", found struct "WavePanel"` for my vec `panels`...
Here is the [diff](https://github.com/minagawah/perlin-experiment/compare/stackoverflow/66405385) for the fix I applied.

Comment: It is about pushing different types to a heterogeneous vec `panels`, and it is a totally different problem. So, I would say, for the original question, you are right! Thanks, kmdoreko! FYI, for the solutions I applied for new problems, I left an editorial note above.